# convert '%/%' from R to matlab

Tags: r, matlab

I'm converting some code from R to matlab and am having difficulty with one command.

```
l0 = 3.5208e+03;
l2 = (l0 - 360 * (l0%/%360))%%360;
= 280.8
```

This is what I need to convert to matlab. So, I've figured out what part of this is in matlab, I can use the mod fucntion.

```
l2 = mod((l0 - 360 * (l0%/%360)),360);
```

but I can't find the equivalent for %/%. Any ideas?

Comment: If I understand correctly, `x%/%y` has the same effect as `floor(x/y)`. I think the function `floor()` exists also in MatLab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consulting the R documentation: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Arithmetic.html, `%/%` stands for **integer** division. In the case of `x%/%y`, just use the [`floor`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/floor.html) function and use this after you perform the division of `x/y` which performs a truncation and rounds down to the nearest integer value, which is the same thing in this particular problem:

```
l2 = mod(l0 - 360*(floor(l0/360)), 360);
```

Checking in MATLAB:

```
>> l0 = 3.5208e+03;
>> l2 = mod(l0 - 360*(floor(l0/360)), 360);
>> l2

l2 =

                     280.8
```

Comment: `idivide` is another possibility.

Comment: @beaker - Why yes it is!  I'll add that in.

Comment: @beaker - On second thought, you can't.  `l0` in the OP's problem is floating-point.  `idivide` requires integer inputs.

Comment: So, what does %*% mean in matlab: would it be floor (10*360)?

Comment: That's matrix multiplication if I read the docs carefully. So for this instance, yes